# Convert milisecond to date to compare to today's date

Tags: date, datetime, neo4j, cypher, milliseconds

I have a set of data stored in neo4j in milliseconds.

I'm trying to get the data then change it to date format and compare it to today's date in where clause to get Media posts for today only.

[image]

I have tried with these

```
MATCH (media:Media) 
RETURN date(datetime({millisecond:media.dateCreated}))
```

and it returns

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.ArgumentError: year must be specified

next, I've tried

```
MATCH (media:Media) 
RETURN apoc.date.field(media.dateCreated)
```

and it returns

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function
>   'apoc.date.field' (line 2, column 28 (offset: 45)) "MATCH
>   (media:Media) RETURN apoc.date.field(media.dateCreated)" ^

I have tried multiple ways that more or less return the same kind of error

I expect the data to be shown in date format instead of milliseconds.

Comment: Unknown function means you don't have **apoc** installed.

Comment: @Raj is there other workaround to that ? because i don't have other privilege to change/install/modify the db. only to read the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `epochMillis` to create the `date` from `milliseconds`.

```
MATCH (media:Media) 
RETURN date(datetime({epochMillis:media.dateCreated}))
```

**This returns the date in the format as shown in the following screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
RETURN datetime({epochMillis: 1475292465000});
```

returns the `datetime` that corresponds to the epoch timestamp `1475292465000`:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"datetime({epochMillis: 1475292465000})"│
╞════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"2016-10-01T03:27:45Z"                  │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If you actually want a `date`, you can use this query:

```
RETURN date(datetime({epochMillis: 1475292465000}));
```